# Recaptcha Codeigniter weird Error

Tags: html, codeigniter, recaptcha

When i include the CodeIgniter library on my website
I have this : 
[SEE THE PROBLEM HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR4XW.png)
A blank after the body tag 
This is caused by the recaptcha library , because when i have removed it , the blank have disappeared

Need some help ;)

Comment: We need at least some code

Answer (score 0):

My code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
   <head>
      <title>Razal</title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <META NAME="description" CONTENT="Serveur privé Dofus 1.29.1">
        <META NAME="author" CONTENT="Ichiga">
<link href="https://www.razal.eu/style/css/style_v13.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://www.razal.eu/style/css/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="javascript">
   <!--
      if (top.location!= self.location)
      {
        top.location = self.location.href
      }

      function ToogleMobileMenu()
      {
        document.getElementById("div-left").classList.toggle('div-left-open');
      }

      function UpdateMinViewIpad()
      {
        var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
        if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width';}
        else{viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-height';}
      }

      // BUG orientation portrait/lanscape IOS //
      if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))
      {
        UpdateMinViewIpad();
        document.addEventListener('orientationchange', function ()
        {
          UpdateMinViewIpad();
          }, false);
      }

      //-->
</script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="div-header">
         <div class="div-header-content">
         </div>
        <div class="div-bar-menu">
   <div class="div-menu">
      <img src="https://www.razal.eu/style/img/menu_separator.png">
      <a href="https://www.razal.eu/">Accueil</a>
      <img src="https://www.razal.eu/style/img/menu_separator.png">
      <a href="https://www.razal.eu/accueil/jouer">Rejoindre Razal</a>
      <img src="https://www.razal.eu/style/img/menu_separator.png">
      <a href="https://www.razal.eu/accueil/classement">Classements</a>
      <img src="https://www.razal.eu/style/img/menu_separator.png">
      <a href="https://www.razal.eu/forum">Forum</a>
      <img src="https://www.razal.eu/style/img/menu_separator.png">
      <a onclick="alert('à venir')" href="#">Vidéos</a>
      <img src="https://www.razal.eu/style/img/menu_separator.png">
   </div>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-content">
         <div id="div-left" class="div-left">
   <div class="div-floater-menu" onclick="ToogleMobileMenu();">
      <img src="images/floatter-menu.png" alt="menu">
   </div>


    <div class="div-box">
      <a href="https://www.razal.eu/utilisateur/inscription"><button class="pure-button pure-button-active" style="width:100%;" id="vote">Créer un compte</button></a>
    </div>


        <div class="div-box">
      <legend>Connexion</legend>
<hr>
<form action="https://www.razal.eu/utilisateur/connexion" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
  <fieldset>

   <label for="username">Nom de compte</label>
   <div class="pure-u-3-2">
   <input class="pure-u-1" id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nom de compte">
   </div>

   <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
   <div class="pure-u-3-2">
   <input class="pure-u-1" id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">se connecter</button>
  </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="div-box">
  <legend>Voter</legend>
  <a href="http://rpg-paradize.com/?page=vote&vote=106388" target="_blank"><img style="width:100%" src="https://www.razal.eu/style/img/rpg.png"></a>
</div>




</div>
         <div class="div-page">
            <div class="div-box">

               <h2>Formulaire d'inscription</h2>
               <hr class="hrtitle" />
               
         <div class="pure-u-1-4">
       </div>
       <div class="pure-u-1-3">
        <form action="https://www.razal.eu/utilisateur/inscription" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
     <fieldset>

      <label for="username">Nom de compte</label>
            <small style="font-size:13px; color:#7C0C0C;"></small>
      <input id="username" name="username" type="text">

            <label for="email">Adresse e-mail</label>
            <small style="font-size:13px; color:#7C0C0C;"></small>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email">

            <label for="nickname">Pseudo</label>
            <small style="font-size:13px; color:#7C0C0C;"></small>
      <input id="nickname" name="nickname" type="text">

      <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
            <small style="font-size:13px; color:#7C0C0C;"></small>
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password">

            <label for="password">Confirmation MDP</label>
            <small style="font-size:13px; color:#7C0C0C;"></small>
      <input id="password" name="passwordconfirm" type="password" >

            <p><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfDgB0TAAAAANw_dSy0Pd-ezJMRTko_UHmpcm6R"></div>
            <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fr" async defer></script></p>

      <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">S'inscrire</button>
     </fieldset>

    </div>
      </form>
    </div>
            </div>
            <br>
         </div>
         <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`&#65279;` entity looks like a result of including files saved in UTF-8 with BOM.

I suggest to check for files encoding, maybe if you are working with different conflicting formats.